# Steam Does Not Recognize Insurgence: Sandstorm as Closed

Tags: steam, technical-issues, insurgency-sandstorm

I just played Insurgency: Sandstorm earlier today, and then left to do some other things. When I came back to start it, Steam said it was already running, even though it was not. Restarting Steam fixed it, but then when I opened up the game again, it would not connect to the server and was laggy, so I went to restart it to see if that fixed the problem, but then Steam again said it was still open. I close the game using the quit button in game, and there is nothing in task manager to say it is still open. Steam won't close properly (I had to use task manager). When there is a game that is not open that it thinks is open, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: How are you closing the game? When Steam states the game is still running, is the game executable still in Task Manager when you experience this issue?  Does Steam show the game as running in the Library list?

Comment: @TimmyJim I close the game with the quit button in the menu, and there is nothing in Task Manager.

Comment: I've run into this with some different games.  At least one has no more running executable, but Steam still thinks it's running.  Only solution I've come up with is to reboot the computer.

Comment: That's because your game have multiple processes in task manager, not always named with game name (so it's hard to stop it manually). When it happens, you can try to stop this / these processes manually, but it'safer to reboot the computer

Comment: @damadam But when I restart Steam, it no longer says its running, and then when I start it again, I get no error anywhere saying its already running.

Comment: That's because Steam closed all processes attached to him, but I think it's annoying to restart Steam if you stop your game

Comment: @damadam Well I could not restart Steam because it was trying to close the game, and after a half an hour of watching it try, I shut it down it with Task Manager, so it did not get to close anything.

Comment: Might be better off submitting a ticket to Steam about it.